# Writing the DNN output to csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am doing the inference stage of my trained Deep neural network. The output of my model is like that:

```
tensor([19])
tensor([25])
tensor([18])
```

I want to save the output in raws at a CSV file to do some statistical analysis. I tried this

```
for data in (dataloader):
 z_eval = model_back(enhanced.float().to(device))
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    gc.collect()

    pred = [torch.max(z.detach().cpu(), dim=1)[1] for z in z_eval]
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    gc.collect()
    pred_test = pred[0]
    print(pred_test)
    #np.savetxt('output.csv', pred_test,delimiter= ',')
    prediction = pd.DataFrame(pred_test, columns=['predictions']).to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

The problem is that it saves only the last value only not all values, so How can I force it to save all the values.

Answer (score 0):

use list to keep data and save to csv after for

```
pred_test =[]

for data in (dataloader):
  z_eval = model_back(enhanced.float().to(device))
  torch.cuda.empty_cache()
  gc.collect()
  pred = [torch.max(z.detach().cpu(), dim=1)[1] for z in z_eval]
  torch.cuda.empty_cache()
  gc.collect()
  pred_test += pred[0]
  print(pred_test)
  #np.savetxt('output.csv', pred_test,delimiter= ',')
prediction = pd.DataFrame(pred_test, columns=['predictions']).to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

Comment: Do you mean to save the output in the list and write the list in the csv file

Comment: I edited my answer and, I put code